# Disabled products missing in product grid

Tags: admin, product-grid, magento2.2.3

All my disabled products don't show up in the product admin grid. I have no filters enabled on the view and tried re-indexing several times.

I'm on version 2.2.3

[image]

The screen above shows 89 products but I know if I can guess an unpublished product ID I can get to it by making the url manually.

Comment: Do you have multi stores/store view/websites?

Comment: I do one is not in use just a demo, I have tried changing the filter for each store but the results do not change.

Comment: Can u please check  grid setting at product grid.Please cross check it. Also Check customization ,may be override the grid collection

Comment: @AmitBera what do you mean by customisation? a module? see screenshot above.

Answer (score 2):

For other people with this issue (who do not want to update stuff directly in the database). I manage to fix this issue by simply forcing back the "Default View" as the user.

[image: Image showing the location of the Default View button]

Comment: Thaaaank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

We managed the same issue deleting all the records of the user where namespace="product_listing" in the table ui_bookmarks. Still no idea how to reproduce and properly fix it.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a go, what is that table for?

Comment: Well that table is meant to save the configuration that users set for their grids, filters, columns, sorting, etc. However, I recently found that the problem in my case was that some products wasn't included in the prices index table, so ordering the table by price was the real cause of having less products in the result, and just sorting by another columns we ended with all the result I.e. ID. I guess this is a Magento's bug, so I'm trying to document it to create the issue report in Github. I'll paste the link here after sending the report.